# Rails activerecord where to sql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How to get sql for only condition?

`Lead.where(status: 1).to_sql`

`` SELECT `leads`.* FROM `leads`  WHERE `leads`.`status` = 1 ``

I need only the condition to sql. ie,
`` leads.`status` = 1 ``

Also i have default scope. From that i need only that scope to sql

Comment: I feel like there's some information missing from this question. What are you trying to achieve by this? If you just need the SQL fragment you could easily write it as a string. If you want to execute the SQL, then you don't need to_sql at all.

Comment: just `leads.status = 1` doens't make sense. How will you interpret the information for joins and aliased tables?

Comment: @AJFaraday Its just an example. I have to execute complex sql. But depending on the user role the scope will change. So i need to convert that scope in to sql. Then only i can add that scope sql to my raw sql.

Comment: @KumarSiva Why not just generate the query you want with activerecord?

Comment: Thats to complex to generate. I need to add joins and conditions depending on various checks. And also i want to insert that records to db again. So i am using select and insert in an single query.
EX ```INSERT INTO courses (name, location, gid)
SELECT name, location, 1
FROM   courses
WHERE  cid = 2```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `Arel::SelectManager#where_sql`:

```
>> Lead.where(status: 1).arel.where_sql
=> "WHERE \"leads\".\"status\" = $1"
```

Comment: Is there any option to get only condition string without **WHERE**

Comment: You could write a custom visitor to do that: https://gist.github.com/tcopeland/9715f83c7cb516209491996bf2442476

Comment: This answer helped me resolve a slightly different problem. For some reason, as of Rails 5.2.1, all the `query.to_sql` values in my specs started returning an empty string. So I had to refactor them to be able to inspect the `where` clause for specific params.

Comment: This leaves bindings as ? rather than filling in their values. If you need the actual bindings you can use the custom visitor as suggested by Tom Copeland by using a `Collectors::SubstituteBinds.new(engine.connection, Collectors::SQLString.new)`. You will also need to define a way to create a new one of those for the inner visitor. You can create a method on the collector to create a new instance with the same quoter `@quoter` and call that method for the inner visitor.

Comment: @KumarSiva Yes! `arel.where_clauses`. This can help in doing OR queries in loops. You can build each part of the query using the AR interface then use `where_clauses` and join them.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
Lead.where(status: 1).values[:where].ast.to_sql
```

We are in the internals of ActiveRecord here, so it comes without guarantee of course.